How to Filter a Multi-Choice Column in a PowerApps Vertical Gallery Using a Dropdown?
I have a table in SharePoint with several columns, one of which is a multi-choice column named Group. I've created a vertical gallery in PowerApps to display the data and added a dropdown control (named drpGroup) to filter the gallery based on the selected group.
I attempted to use the following formulas to filter the gallery, but neither of them seems to be working:
First try:
Filter('Projects',(IsBlank(drpGroup.Selected),Concat(Group, Value) in drpGroup.Selected))


Second try:
Filter('Projects',(IsBlank(drpGroup.Selected),Concat(Group, Value) = drpGroup.Selected))


Could someone please help me understand why these formulas aren't working and suggest a correct approach to filter the gallery based on the multi-choice "Group" column?
